# How does InkCanvas calculate bezier control points when drawing smooth paths?

Tags: wpf, bezier, inkcanvas

InkCanvas in WPF draws very smooth curves when using a touch screen but when using a mouse it looses it's smoothness. Why does InkCanvas use different techniques when using a mouse or a touch screen?

To draw a smooth Bezier-curve between points it seem to be necessary to calculate where to put the control points (one for quad and two for cubic bezier). **My question is how InkCanvas calculates these points when using a touch screen?**

I'm going to render a cubic bezier path from mouse points (not WPF) so I'm looking for code to calculate these control points. I noticed that InkCanvas does it very well but was suprised that it did it differently when using a mouse.

Comment: are you sure that's your question? Because you immediately follow up with "I won't be using WPF", so why would it matter how WPF's InkCanvas does it if you're simply interested in "how do I invent control points for a freehand drawn shape"?

Comment: Well, I'd like to know a method to "invent control points" that is similar or just as InkCanvas does it.